# I have used several system.out.print statements , but I am required to use only one sop statement

Tags: java

This is the code and it completely works fine. But I just need to use one SOP statement and I do not know how to do it :(

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab4
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String Expression;
        int exp=0;
        String Val1=null,Val2=null;
        String Compute=null;
        Expression=input.nextLine().trim();
        if(Expression.trim().contains("<")&&!Expression.trim().contains("="))
        {
            exp=Expression.trim().indexOf("<");
            Compute="<";
            Val1=Expression.trim().substring(0, exp);
            Val2=Expression.trim().substring(exp+1,Expression.trim().length());
        }
        else if(Expression.trim().contains(">")&&!Expression.trim().contains("="))
        {
            exp=Expression.trim().indexOf(">");
            Compute=">";
            Val1=Expression.trim().substring(0, exp);
            Val2=Expression.trim().substring(exp+1,Expression.trim().length());
        }
        else if(Expression.trim().contains("<="))
        {
            exp=Expression.trim().indexOf("<=");
            Compute="<=";
            Val1=Expression.trim().substring(0, exp);
            Val2=Expression.trim().substring(exp+2,Expression.trim().length());
        }
        else if(Expression.trim().contains(">="))
        {
            exp=Expression.trim().indexOf(">=");
            Compute=">=";
            Val1=Expression.trim().substring(0, exp);
            Val2=Expression.trim().substring(exp+2,Expression.trim().length());
        }

        int num1,num2;
        num1=Integer.parseInt(Val1.trim());
        num2=Integer.parseInt(Val2.trim());
        if(Compute.equals("<"))
        {
            if(num1<num2) 
                System.out.println("True");
            else
                System.out.println(""+num1+">="+num2+"");
        }
        else if(Compute.equals(">"))
        {
            if(num1>num2) 
                System.out.println("True");
            else
                System.out.println(""+num1+"<"+num2+"");
        }
        else if(Compute.equals("<="))
        {
            if(num1<=num2) 
                System.out.println("True");
            else
                System.out.println(""+num1+">="+num2+"");
        }
        else if(Compute.equals(">="))
        {
            if(num1>=num2) 
                System.out.println("True");
            else
                System.out.println(""+num1+"<"+num2+"");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a single `message` String (or use a `StringBuilder`); and then **print** that.

Comment: So this program is to compare two values using relational operator. So the statement which you said , how do I use that sir.

Comment: *Expanding on comment by @ElliottFrisch:* Declare a `String message` local variable, change all the `System.out.println(xxx);` statements to `message = xxx;`, then do `System.out.println(message);` at the end. No need for `StringBuilder`. --- *Unrelated:* `""+num1+">="+num2+""` is the same as `num1+">="+num2`. No need to concatenate empty strings there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your `println` calls, and instead assign a single `String message` in your `if` blocks and then print that message afterwards. Something like,

```
String message = "";
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(Val1.trim());
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(Val2.trim());
if (Compute.equals("<")) {
    if (num1 < num2)
        message = "True";
    else
        message = "" + num1 + ">=" + num2;
} else if (Compute.equals(">")) {
    if (num1 > num2)
        message = "True";
    else
        message = "" + num1 + "<=" + num2;
} else if (Compute.equals("<=")) {
    if (num1 <= num2)
        message = "True";
    else
        message = "" + num1 + ">" + num2;
} else if (Compute.equals(">=")) {
    if (num1 >= num2)
        message = "True";
    else
        message = "" + num1 + "<" + num2;
}
System.out.println(message);
```